# How to modify this sqlite SQL query so that inner join filter less?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have this table `name_currency` in sqlite3.

```
name,   currency,   price
AA,     SGD,        1
BB,     USD,        2
CC,     EUR,        3
```

I need to process the price in this manner.

```
if currency == "SGD", price = price*2 
if currency == "USD", price = price*Y
if currency == "EUR", price = price*Z
```

The values of Y, Z needs to be retrieved from another table `currency_multiplier`. This is how currency_multiplier looks like.

```
currency,   rate
SGDUSD,     3    #value of Y
SGDEUR,     4    #value of Z
```

The desired output table will look like this after processing price column;

```
name,   currency,   price
AA,     SGD,        2
BB,     USD,        6
CC,     EUR,        12
```

Here is the query I wrote to solve this problem.

```
SELECT name_currency.name, 
       name_currency.currency, 
       name_currency.dividend_yield*currency_multiplier.rate as price, 
from name_currency
INNER JOIN currency_multiplier
    on name_currency.currency = substr(currency_multiplier.currency,4,3)
```

The output of the query I wrote looks like this;

```
name,   currency,   price
BB,     USD,        6
CC,     EUR,        12
```

One of the rows with currency `SGD` is missing. The inner join filtered too much. How can I modify the query to solve the problem? I am welcome to totally new queries to solve this problem.

Comment: I see that you are asking very similar questions in close succession.  You might want to try a complete solution of your real problem, and then just post a single question to cover everything.

Comment: Also, I recommend having separate `from_currency` and `to_currency` columns in your forex table.  You could run into problems if the currency codes could somehow overlap, are not the same length, etc.

Comment: @Tim, sorry. Each time, I thought I got the complete solution after asking each question but I kept encountering roadblocks. Asking a single question to cover everything is against the culture of stack overflow. It is akin to asking to be spoon-fed. Question will get down-voted.

Comment: I agree...maybe I commented this way because I probably could have gathered everything myself in one question, doesn't mean that's true for everyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join instead of inner join

```
SELECT name_currency.name, 
       name_currency.currency, 
       case when currency_multiplier.rate is null then  name_currency.dividend_yield*2 else name_currency.dividend_yield*currency_multiplier.rate end as price, 
from name_currency
left JOIN currency_multiplier
    on name_currency.currency = substr(currency_multiplier.currency,4,3)
```

Comment: Oh boy you really make me feel stupid. Thank you for the brilliant answer.

Comment: I will have to wait for 11 more minutes to mark it because you answered too quickly. Your mind works too fast. haha.

Comment: You should have a check on the first three characters as well to make sure that the starting currency is `SGD`.  And also, a left join may not make sense in any case, because how do you handle a missing forex?  This is not well defined.